# Header with section short title and chapter short title using KOMA-Script

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, koma-script

I'm trying to set header with chapter title on the right and section title on the left (with appropriate numbers in front of them). Also, I need to use short titles for header and long titles for ToC.

I am using single side document KOMA-Script Book with `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Please help …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set option `autoneside=false` for package `scrlayer-scrpage` if you want to use both chapter and section titles in a onesided document.

Set class option `headings=optiontohead` if the optional argument of sectioning commands should be used for the page header and not for ToC by default.

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontohead,
  twoside=false
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[Short chapter title]{Long chapter title for document and TOC}
\section[Short section title]{Long section title for document and TOC}
\lipsum
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

**Update** (regarding a comment below)

To avoid two equal entries on both sides of the header (eg. in a TOC with more than one page or a chapter without sections) you can use

```
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  headings=optiontohead,
  twoside=false
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[Short chapter title]{Long chapter title for document and TOC}
\lipsum[1-12]
\section[Short section title]{Long section title for document and TOC}
\lipsum
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Suggested solution works fine only if you have chapter and section on the same page of the document. If you put the chapter name and than type some text (for example next two or three pages) and than insert the section, you will have chapter short titles on both sides of the header all the way to the page where section is located, which is not so good... Is there any way to overcome this issue? Many  Thanks!

Comment: @Predrag_M See my updated answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks!